# What is algorithm to find K for finding medians in two sorted array in leetcode

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

The [solution](https://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/leetcode-median-of-two-sorted-arrays-java/) implementing find medians in two sorted array is awesome. However, I am still very confused about code to calculate **K**

```
var aMid = aLength * k / (aLength + bLength)
var bMid = k - aMid - 1
```

I guess this is the key part of this algorithm which I really dont know why is calculated like this. To explain more clearly what I mean, the core logic is **divide and conquer**, considering the fact that **different size** **list** should be divided differently. I wonder why this formula is working perfectly.

Can someone give me some insight about it. I searched lots of online documents and it is very hard to find materials to explain this part well.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The link shows two different ways of computing the comparison points in each array: one always uses `k/2`, even if the array doesn't have that many elements; the other (which you quote) tries to distribute the comparison points based on the size of the arrays.

As can be seen from these two examples, neither of which is optimal, it doesn't make much difference how you compute the comparison points, as long as the size of the the two components is generally linear in K (using a fixed size of 5 for one of the comparison points won't work, for example.)

The algorithm effectively reduces the problem size by either aMid or bMid on each iteration. Ideally, the problem size would be reduced by k/2; and that's the computation you should use if both arrays have at least k/2 members. If one has two few members, you can set the comparison point for the array to its last element, and compute the other comparison point so that the total is k - 1. If you end up discarding all of the elements from some array, you can then immediately return element k of the other array.

That strategy will usually perform fewer iterations than either of the proposals in your link, but it is still O(log k).